# Gson: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT

Tags: java, gson

I am trying to read a simple JSON response:

```
{
  "response": "ok"
}
```

Here is my code:

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
String response = null;
boolean success = false;
reader.beginObject();
if (reader.hasNext()) {
  String token = reader.nextName();
  if (token.equals("response")) {
    response = reader.nextString();
  } else {
    reader.skipValue();
  }
}
reader.endObject();
reader.close();
```

But I am getting this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected `STRING` but was `BEGIN_OBJECT`

I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Would strongly recommend using `gson` library for something like this....removes ton of boilerplate code and less error prone.

Comment: JsonReader is in gson library

Comment: https://github.com/google/gson .....in particular to map your Java POJOs to/from json rather than using custom code.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your parser **is** fine. If the code snippet you provided really belongs to the exception stack trace you're getting, then I believe that the `response` property of the JSON you're trying to parse has a value other than a string. For example,

```
{ "response": "ok" }
```

can be parsed by your parser just fine. However, the closest exception message you can get with your parser is a JSON similar to the one below:

```
{ "response": {"status": "ok"} }
```

that should fail with something like

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 16 path $.response

Also note that Gson reports the problematic location at least in its latest versions (I tested it with Gson 2.5). Just make sure you're getting the expected input. If you believe the response must be in the format you mentioned, then just try to trace the input stream and find the differences. Tracing an input stream in its simplest but not the most efficient implementation, and you could have a slightly more efficient tracing reader like this:

```java
private static Reader traceReader(final Reader reader) {
    return new Reader() {
        @Override
        public int read(final char[] buffer, final int offset, final int length)
                throws IOException {
            final int read = reader.read(buffer, offset, length);
            if ( read != -1 ) {
                // or any other appropriate tracing output here
                out.print(new String(buffer, offset, read));
                out.flush();
            }
            return read;
        }

        @Override
        public void close()
                throws IOException {
            reader.close();
        }
    };
}
```

with:

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(traceReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8")))
```

Then just re-check if you're really getting `{ "response": "ok" }`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I checked the response with postman and I can confirm that is the response I initially posted here.

Comment: @student Postman and your application request headers set may differ, thus the server can respond differently to your application and Postman.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding this here.
In my case, I got this error because I attempted to parse an JSON object directly to an ENUM. GSON was expecting a string directly instead of a JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I made a mistake modeling the reponse. My error is an object and I modeled it as a String.
Taking a closer look at my API response and modeling fixed it

Answer (score 0):

The idea for solving this is something like this example:
Your JSON says that `dCharg` is an object, not a `String`:

```
"dCharg":{"TEXT":1000}
```

If it was supposed to be a String, it would have looked like:

```
"dCharg":"1000"
```

Maybe You could design like as follows

```
public class BaseEmployee{/* stuffs */}

public class RegularEmployee extends BaseEmployee{/* stuffs */}

public class Contractors extends BaseEmployee{/* stuffs */}
```