# Retrofit JsonArray recyclerview Exception

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

im trying to get data from http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users and display it in recyclerview . i don't need all the columns from the api

public interface APIService {

```
@GET("/users")
    Call<JSONResponse>getJSON();}
```

public class JSONResponse {

```
private UserInfo[] Info;

public  UserInfo[] getInfo(){
    return Info;
}}
```

.
    public class UserInfo {

```
@SerializedName("id")
private String id;
@SerializedName("name")
private String name;
@SerializedName("city")
private String city;
@SerializedName("company")
private String company;
@SerializedName("email")
private String email;
@SerializedName("phone")
private String phone;
@SerializedName("lat")
private double lat;
@SerializedName("lng")
private double lng;
@SerializedName("website")
private String website;

//getter methods }
```

in the main activity

```
private void loadJSON() {
    Call<JSONResponse>call = apiService.getJSON();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONResponse>() {
        @Override   
        public void onResponse(Call<JSONResponse> call, Response<JSONResponse> response) {


            JSONResponse jsonResponse = response.body();                  
            data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getInfo()));
            adapter = new DataAdapter(data);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JSONResponse>call,Throwable t) {
            Log.d("Error", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

i'm getting  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $.

i tried change to`Call<List<UserInfo>> getJSON();`  but i got  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 19 column 17 path $[0].company

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gson: Expected a string but was BEGIN\_OBJECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41649731/gson-expected-a-string-but-was-begin-object)

Answer (score 0):

use this model class

```
public class UserInfo {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("username")
@Expose
private String username;
@SerializedName("email")
@Expose
private String email;
@SerializedName("address")
@Expose
private Address address;
@SerializedName("phone")
@Expose
private String phone;
@SerializedName("website")
@Expose
private String website;
@SerializedName("company")
@Expose
private Company company;

public Integer getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public String getUsername() {
return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
this.username = username;
}

public String getEmail() {
return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
this.email = email;
}

public Address getAddress() {
return address;
}

public void setAddress(Address address) {
this.address = address;
}

public String getPhone() {
return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
this.phone = phone;
}

public String getWebsite() {
return website;
}

public void setWebsite(String website) {
this.website = website;
}

public Company getCompany() {
return company;
}

public void setCompany(Company company) {
this.company = company;
}

}
```

Then change interface like this

```
public interface APIService {

@GET("/users")
Call<List<UserInfo>> getJSON();
}
```

and your network call function should be like this

```
private void loadJSON() {
Call<List<UserInfo>> call = apiService.getJSON();
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<UserInfo>>() {
    @Override   
    public void onResponse(Call<List<UserInfo>> call, Response<List<UserInfo>> response) {


        List<UserInfo> user = response.body();                  
        data = new ArrayList<>(user);
        adapter = new DataAdapter(data);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<UserInfo>> call,Throwable t) {
        Log.d("Error", t.getMessage());
    }
});
}
```

Comment: i have an error at this line:
UserInfo user = response.body();

Incompatible types.
Required:
sd.task.UserInfo

Found:
java.util.List
<sd.task.UserInfo>

Comment: change `UserInfo user = response.body()`; to `List<UserInfo> user = response.body()`

Comment: now i got an error at:
data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(user));


Unchecked assignment: 'java.util.ArrayList' to 'java.util.ArrayList<sd.task.UserInfo>'
Unchecked call to 'ArrayList(Collection<? extends E>)' as a member of raw type 'java.util.ArrayList'

Comment: @user3178058 change `data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(user));` to `data = new ArrayList<>(user);`